# Moving the div evenly aorund inside the grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

How can I make the green square always land on the center of the blue square; it works when I first hit the up key but after that it lands in different positions.

Also, I want to be able to keep the green square from going outside the grid; as you can see, I'm really green when it comes to coding and maybe this takes more complex coding than I realized. But the most common advice has been to try, Google, and ask on forums.

```js
const mun = document.querySelector('.mun')

let xAxis = 0
let yAxis = 0


function control(e) {
  switch (e.key) {
    case 'ArrowLeft':
      xAxis -= 80;
      mun.style.left = xAxis + 'px';
      break;

    case 'ArrowRight':
      xAxis += 80;
      mun.style.left = xAxis + 'px';
      break;

    case 'ArrowUp':
      yAxis -= 80;
      mun.style.top = yAxis + 'px';
      console.log(yAxis)
      break;

    case 'ArrowDown':
      yAxis += 80;
      mun.style.top = yAxis + 'px';
      break;
  }
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', control)
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.one,
.two,
.three,
.four,
.six,
.seven,
.eight,
.nine {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#five {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.mun {
  background-color: green;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 31%;
  left: 32%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div id="five">Five
    <div class="mun"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="six">Six</div>
  <div class="seven">Seven</div>
  <div class="eight">Eight</div>
  <div class="nine">Nine</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/erashishkatoch/zsgL2cjx/2/  I added one check to not go beyond the right side. same you can implement with the other directions

Answer (score 1):

There you go. You should be able to improve this by finding an algorithm that can find the neighboring elements. Here is the jsfiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/28dzk1e7/25/

```js
    const mun = document.querySelector('.mun')

        let matrixSize = 3
    let currentPos = 5
    let positions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    let neighbours = {
      1:[2,4],
      2:[1,3,5],
      3:[2,6],
      4:[1,5,7],
      5:[2,4,6,8],
      6:[3,5,9],
      7:[4,8],
      8:[7,5,9],
      9:[6,8],
    }
    
    
    
    
    let goTo = (targetPos)=>{
      if(neighbours[currentPos].includes(targetPos)){
         let targetContainer = document.querySelector(`[data-num="${targetPos}"]`);
         targetContainer.appendChild(mun)
         currentPos=targetPos
        }
    }
    

    function control(e) {
        switch (e.key) {
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                  goTo(currentPos - 1)
                break;
     
            case 'ArrowRight':
                        goTo(currentPos + 1)
                break;
        
            case 'ArrowUp':
                             goTo(currentPos - matrixSize)
                break;
         
            case 'ArrowDown':
                        goTo(currentPos + matrixSize)
                break;    
       }
     };
     
      document.addEventListener('keydown', control)
```

```css
    .wrapper {
        display: inline-grid;
        grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
        grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }

    .one, .two, .three,
    .four, .six, .seven, .eight, .nine ,.five {
        background-color: blue;
        border: 1px solid black;
        position:relative;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;

    }

    .mun {
        background-color: green;
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

    }
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one" data-num="1">One</div>
    <div class="two" data-num="2">Two</div>
    <div class="three" data-num="3">Three</div>
    <div class="four" data-num="4">Four</div>
    <div class="five" data-num="5">Five
        <div class="mun"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="six" data-num="6">Six</div>
    <div class="seven" data-num="7">Seven</div>
    <div class="eight" data-num="8">Eight</div>
    <div class="nine" data-num="9">Nine</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Voted up for standard centering mun in parent div and also for clean and intelligent javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to not hardcoding based on rows and columns count. Instead, rows/columns count could be retrieved from css code.

Also, the mun div could be created at page load ant put in the div marked by an attribute (selected="true" in this example).
The grid is not necessarily square or even complete.

```js
var rows;
var cols;
var initial_index;
var index;
var boxes;
var mun;

function onload() {
    var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
    var rows_template = window.getComputedStyle(wrapper).getPropertyValue('grid-template-rows');
    rows = rows_template.split(' ').length;
    var cols_template = window.getComputedStyle(wrapper).getPropertyValue('grid-template-columns');
    cols = cols_template.split(' ').length;
    boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
    for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (boxes[i].attributes.getNamedItem('selected') != null) {
            initial_index = i;
            index = i;
            mun = document.createElement("div");
            mun.className = 'mun';
            SetPosition();
            break;
        } 
    }
}

function cursor_keys(event) {
    switch (event.code) {
        case 'ArrowUp':
            if (index - cols >= 0) { index -= cols; SetPosition(); }
                break;
        case 'ArrowDown':
            if (index + cols < boxes.length) { index += cols; SetPosition(); }
                break;
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            if (index % cols > 0) { index--; SetPosition(); }
                break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
            if (index + 1 < boxes.length && (index % cols) != cols - 1) { index++; SetPosition(); }
                break;
        case 'Home':
            index = initial_index;
            SetPosition();
            break;
        case 'PageUp':
            index = 0;
            SetPosition();
            break;
        case 'PageDown':
            index = boxes.length - 1;
            SetPosition();
            break;
    }
}

function SetPosition() {
    boxes[index].appendChild(mun);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onload);
document.addEventListener('keydown', cursor_keys);
```

```css
.wrapper {
        display: inline-grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
        grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: antiquewhite;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .mun {
        background-color: green;
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box">1</div>
        <div class="box">2</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
        <div class="box">4</div>
        <div class="box">5</div>
        <div class="box">6</div>
        <div class="box">7</div>
        <div class="box">8</div>
        <div class="box">9</div>
        <div class="box">10</div>
        <div class="box" selected="true">11</div>
        <div class="box">12</div>
        <div class="box">13</div>
        <div class="box">14</div>
        <div class="box">15</div>
        <div class="box">16</div>
        <div class="box">17</div>
</div>
```